# What is the best practise when working with 2D arrays in C, if it exists?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array, 2d

**Question: What is the best practise when working with 2D arrays in C, if it exists?**

As far as I program in C I always get my mind confused whenever using 2D arrays would be convenient.

**I like representing 2D arrays by 1D array**.  But time to time I get an advice that I should be using some other representation.

Lastly, I tried to use typedef for defining my own 2D matrix type. But I got into troubles as I wanted to change values inside a function and have it changed also outside the function. Code follows:

```
typedef struct mat2d {
   const int cols = 2;
   const unsigned int rows = 5;
   double data[5][2];
};



int print_mat(mat2d A) {
   for (int i = 0; i < A.rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < A.cols; j++) {
           printf("%f ", A.data[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}

int fill_ones(mat2d A) {
   
   for (int i = 0; i < A.rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < A.cols; j++) {
           A.data[i][j] = 1.0;
       }
   }
   
   printf("Inside the function fill_ones:\n");
   print_mat(A);
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}


int main() {
   int x = 10;
   int y = 25;
   int z = x + y;
   struct mat2d A;
   
   fill_ones(A);
   printf("Outside the function fill_ones:\n");
   print_mat(A);

}

/* OUTPUT:
Inside the function fill_ones:
1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 

Outside the function fill_ones:
0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 
*/
```

Clearly, I also lack some understanding of C and "permanence of modification" or what is acctualy being send to the function, because I do not understand why the function did not change the matrix, maybe I mixed up the advice, but that is a different question.

Comment: You cant have any output as your code will not compile in C language. You compiled it using C++ compiler.

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrays. `fill_ones(A);` passes a copy of `A` to `fill_ones`. Anything `fill_ones` does with it only modifies the copy. That is true whether you pass a structure containing an array or a single `int`. If you passed a pointer or a structure containing a pointer, then the called routine could use the pointer to change the pointed-to objects. That happens automatically when you pass an array directly; the array is converted to a pointer, and then changes to the pointed-to data are visible in the calling routine. But `A` is not an array, so it is not converted.

Comment: You cannot initialize `struct` members inside a `struct` type specifier as you are doing in your `struct mat2d`. Also, the `typedef` isn't naming any type. I guess you intended to define the typedef name `mat2d` since you use that elsewhere in your code.

Comment: "I like representing 2D arrays by 1D array" Sounds like a pretty bad habit

Comment: You need to study how function arguments are passed.... This has nothing to do with array being 2D. You will see the same if you used a 1D array.

Answer (score 1):

Structs can be passed by value. You pass the struct by the value to the function. The function modifies the **local** copy of the structure. You need to pass the reference:

```
typedef struct {
   size_t cols;
   size_t rows;
   double data[];
} mat2d;

mat2d *createmat(size_t rows, size_t cols) 
{
    mat2d *d2 = malloc(sizeof(*d2) + sizeof(d2 -> data[0]) * rows * cols);
    if(d2)
    {
        d2 -> rows = rows;
        d2 -> cols = cols;
    }
    return d2;
}


int print_mat(mat2d *A) 
{
    double (*pdata)[A -> cols] = (void *)A -> data;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A -> rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < A -> cols; j++) {
           printf("%f ", pdata[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int fill_ones(mat2d *A) {
    double (*pdata)[A -> cols] = (void *)A -> data;   
    for (int i = 0; i < A -> rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A -> cols; j++) {
            pdata[i][j] = 1.0;
        }
   }
   
   printf("Inside the function fill_ones:\n");
   print_mat(A);
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}


int main() {
    mat2d *A;

    A = createmat(4,7);
    if(A)
    {
        fill_ones(A);
        printf("Outside the function fill_ones:\n");
        print_mat(A);
    }
    free(A);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7qab5ncc1

Comment: Won't unflattening the 1-D `data[]` array to 2-D break the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `A -> rows` is not idiomatic C and normally indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `A->rows`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler then I am 30y+ experience tyro. I hate it with no spaces. *"Use A->rows"* I will definitely not.